# Using StopWatch to calculate running time in c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, textbox, stopwatch

This is my code:

```
 public State Create_eNfa(string sRegExPosfix)
      {
          var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
          //bla bla bla

          Debug.Assert(stackNfa.Count == 1);
          var expr = (NfaExpression) stackNfa.Pop();
          expr.FinalState().AcceptingState = true;

          watch.Stop();
          var time=watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;          

          return expr.StartState();

      }
```

Now, the variable "time" included what I want, but the problem is how to move "time" to my form. I want to put `textBox.Text=time.toString();` in my form.

Finally, after my Create_eNFA called in my code, the textBox will show the result, How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

In your context, your method needs to return more than one value and having the return value already taken for the `State` value then you need to pass the `time` variable as an [out parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx).

```
public State Create_eNfa(string sRegExPosfix, out long time)
{
   var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   .....
   watch.Stop();
   time = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;          
   return expr.StartState();
 }
```

and call it with

```
 long time;
 State result = Create_eNfa(sRegExPosfix, out time);
 textBox.Text=time.toString();
```

The `out time` parameter is a reference to the variable `time` in the calling code and you need to assign a value to it before exiting the `Create_eNfa` method